# I have two different databases, I want do Cloning . So is it possible with out editing pfile i mean spfile

Tags: oracle11gr2

I have two different two databases with different file system.

So I want to do cloning without editing the pfile.

Is it possible or not ?

what is different between user and schema ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the [Oracle 2-day DBA manuals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/backrest.htm#ADMQS009) and about [DataPump](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL100) - `pfile` really does not enter into the ability to clone a database.  You mention you have two databases with different file systems.  DataPump can handle various scenarios.

A user is a user id in the database; the user may own objects like tables in the database; the objects for a user are considered a schema.  You can have hundreds of users but there may be just a few users that are considered application owners that have tables owned by them.  So if you do a schema export you are (usually) exporting all the objects owned by a particular user.